# Docker: should I combine my apt-get install / build / cleanup steps into one big RUN?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM debian:stable-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fp-compiler fp-units-fcl fp-units-net libc6-dev

COPY src /whatwg/wattsi/src

WORKDIR /whatwg/wattsi/src
RUN ./build.sh

RUN rm -rf /whatwg/wattsi/src && \
    apt-get purge -y fp-compiler fp-units-fcl fp-units-net libc6-dev && \
    apt-get autoremove -y

ENTRYPOINT ["/whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi"]
```

As you can see, there are three separate RUN steps: one to install dependencies, one to build, and one to cleanup after building.

I've been poking around to try to figure out why the resulting image is relatively large, and it seems like it's because, even though I do a cleanup step, a layer is retained containing all the installed dependencies.

Should I restructure my Dockerfile like so?

```
FROM debian:stable-slim

COPY src /whatwg/wattsi/src
WORKDIR /whatwg/wattsi/src

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fp-compiler fp-units-fcl fp-units-net libc6-dev && \
    ./build.sh && \
    rm -rf /whatwg/wattsi/src && \
    apt-get purge -y fp-compiler fp-units-fcl fp-units-net libc6-dev && \
    apt-get autoremove -y

ENTRYPOINT ["/whatwg/wattsi/bin/wattsi"]
```

This feels a bit "squashed", and I can't find any documentation explicitly recommending it. All the documentation that says "minimize `RUN` commands" seems to focus on not doing multiple `apt-get` steps; it doesn't talk about squashing everything into one. But maybe it's the right thing to do?

Comment: If you want to keep your image small and you do not need all the dependencies that are installed, have a look at [`multistage builds`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: Thanks @michalk. I tried copying what that page was doing, but ended up with `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each layer in a Docker image is like a commit in version control, in can't change previous layers just like deleting a file in Git won't remove it from from history. So deleting a file from a previous layer doesn't make the image smaller.

Since layers are created at the end of RUN, doing what you're doing is indeed one way to make smaller images. The other, as someone mentioned, is multi-stage builds.

The downside of the single RUN variant is that you have to rerun the *whole* thing every time source code changes. So you need to apt-get all those packages each time instead of relying on Docker's build caching (I wrote a thing explaining the caching here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-caching-model/).

So multi-stage lets you have both faster builds via caching, and small images. But it's complicated to get right, what you did is simpler and easier.

Comment: Thanks! Explaining the downside was helpful; I know see why the single-RUN variant isn't universally recommended in the articles I was reading.

I ended up switching to multi-stage builds (https://github.com/whatwg/wattsi/pull/120) so as to get the best of both worlds. As long as I avoid `alpine`, it seems to work pretty well.